# Img over Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I need to get a mobile image with changing images inside (sliding); so I thought that a Bootstrap carousel overlayed by another image should do the job.

Below is my code, however there are two issues (responsive resizing) and since I am using an absolute positioning, the current section is getting overlayed the next section.

```
<section>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;">Online Dashboard</h2>
    <div class="row" style="margin: 50px 0;">
        <div class="col-6" align="center">
            <div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" style="position: absolute; left: 0; height: 100px; width: 50px;">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active" data-interval="1000">
                    <img src="resources/assets/images/oneplus6_phone_blue_screen.png" style="height: 100px;">
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-interval="1000">
                    <img src="resources/assets/images/oneplus6_phone_red_screen.png" style="height: 100px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <img src="resources/assets/images/oneplus6_phone.png" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100px;">  
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-lg-4">
            <h2>We love brainstorming ideas!</h2>
            <a href="mailto:info@example.com?Subject=Website-Contact%20Form" target="_top"><button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger heartbeat">Contact Us!</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Post full code please

Comment: Hi Post Full Code Snippet - @Luke Galea

Comment: Hi all, I added the next section of the code which to me seems to be the only relevant section. i.e. the other parts such as footer, body, etc should not affect this snippet I think.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Hello, world!</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!--Carousel Wrapper-->
  <div id="carousel-example-2" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
    <!--Indicators-->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#carousel-example-2" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <!--/.Indicators-->
    <!--Slides-->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <div class="view">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(68).jpg" alt="First slide">
          <div class="mask rgba-black-light"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="h3-responsive">Light mask</h3>
          <p>First text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <!--Mask color-->
        <div class="view">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(6).jpg" alt="Second slide">
          <div class="mask rgba-black-strong"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="h3-responsive">Strong mask</h3>
          <p>Secondary text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <!--Mask color-->
        <div class="view">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Slides/img%20(9).jpg" alt="Third slide">
          <div class="mask rgba-black-slight"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3 class="h3-responsive">Slight mask</h3>
          <p>Third text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--/.Slides-->
    <!--Controls-->
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel-example-2" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
    <!--/.Controls-->
  </div>
  <!--/.Carousel Wrapper-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try to z-index with value 1 the slider (the background one if I understood well) and z-index with a value of 2 or higher the mobile image. Or you can invert the z-index value to make the slider over the mobile image.